# Font style doesn't work with new font

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

We seem to have gotten a new font in the last couple of days. This new font family for me is for the most part the below. As most other `font-family`'s use `inherit`.

> ```
> body {
>   font-family: "Open Sans","Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
> }
> ```

With Open Sans the font style doesn't work. Where writing, the following all come out with the normal font style.

```
normal, _italic_, __bold__, ___bold italic___
```

As demoed here:

normal, *italic*, **bold**, ***bold italic***

Screenshot for posterity:

[image: capture]

Comment: Which browser and system are you using? On Safari 10.1.1 on Mac OS Sierra it looks as intended. Same with Chrome 58.0.3029 and Firefox 53.0.3.

Comment: No repro, it looks perfectly fine for me. Win 10 latest Firefox x64.

Comment: I've got the same problem, in both Firefox and Edge. Chrome does show bold and italic text as expected, though. Removing `local("Open Sans")` solves the problem for me, too.

Comment: Was able to reproduce the behaviour on Win8.1 FF54.

Comment: I have the same problem on a Debian buster/sid x86 with Firefox 52.2.0 (32bit).

Comment: @AaronShekey I think I found the problem, and a way to fix it on Firefox, it'd be great if you could look over my answer below. (Note I have no clue on how Chrome works when applying it.)

Comment: I'm seeing this issue with Linux Mint 18.2 and Firefox 55.0.2

Comment: I reported this issue [on Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/302082/italic-bold-markdown-on-code-review-not-working-for-some-browsers)

Comment: I previously saw this reprod on Chrome, and now it has apparently been fixed by a recent update.  Are you seeing any changes on your end?  If so, I can mark this as resolved.

Comment: @Jamal I tested it on my GF's laptop that I think should have had the issue. I also checked the source code, and it looks like the CSS has the below fix too. So I think this has been fixed

Comment: @Peilonrayz Can you provide an edit to your existing answer and accept it? Or accept a new answer?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Update

This problem has been [submitted to Meta.StackExchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/302082/italic-bold-markdown-on-code-review-not-working-for-some-browsers). At the time of this edit, it has not yet been resolved.

---

### Cause

I done some testing on my machine, and found that I have a broken Open Sans font located in `C:\Windows\Fonts`. However even when I deleted this broken font it was re-acquired at some point. I'm unsure if this was due to Windows, or due to a different installer.

If you're affected by this bug, you can test this yourself by removing all `local("Open Sans")` from `/Sites/codereviewmeta/all.css`. On Firefox, in the Style Editor, these are positioned between line 23000 and line 23100. (Scroll to the bottom)

---

This bug currently doesn't affect Chrome, [due to a bug in Chrome](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=627143). This is as, for some reason, it currently ignores the local font, and just downloads the server font.

Otherwise this bug *should* affect all font spec compliant browsers.

---

## Resolution

I looked into this a little more into the fonts that I have and found Windows Explorer was hiding the font family a little:

```
PS C:\Windows\Fonts> ls

    Directory: C:\Windows\Fonts


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
[...]
-a----        3/18/2017   8:58 PM          69316 ntailub.ttf
-a----       10/17/2016   5:09 PM         222412 OpenSans-Light.ttf
-a----        9/11/2012   1:33 PM         217360 OpenSans-Regular.ttf
-a----       10/17/2016   5:09 PM         221328 OpenSans-Semibold.ttf
-a----        3/18/2017   8:58 PM         472216 pala.ttf
[...]
```

Looking into the [Mozilla bug report](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1287089#c1), linked in the Chrome bug report. Which says:

> No, Firefox is correct here AFAICS. The src:local() descriptor takes
>   an individual font *face* name, which may be either the "full name" or
>   the "postscript name", according to the CSS Fonts spec.[1]
>
> In this case, the font's fullname and psname are both "SteveHand", and
>   therefore that is the correct name to use in src:local(). The name
>   "Steve" is the *family* name (which could potentially identify a whole
>   family of "Steve" faces with different weights, widths, italicness,
>   etc), and this is *not* valid for use in the src:local() descriptor.
>
> From a quick look at the Chromium issue mentioned, it sounds like
>   Chromium may be accepting the font *family* name in src:local(). If
>   so, that's a bug (and a violation of the spec).
>
> [1] https://www.w3.org/TR/css-fonts-3/#src-desc

And so replacing `local("Open Sans")` to `local("Open Sans Regular")` - the font name, rather than the family name. It works in Firefox. Leading to the following CSS, for one of the many font-faces:

```
@font-face {
 font-family:"Open Sans";
 font-weight:400;
 font-style:normal;
 src:local("Open Sans Regular"),url("../../Fonts/open-sans/opensans-regular-webfont.woff?v=6602c110b789") format('woff')
}
```

I would do further testing, but Chrome has mini-heart attacks that last a prolonged period of time, when changing the font-family. I'm not even sure if it updates the fonts. However it comes down to having the font installed locally.

Comment: I finally got fed up with the behaviour and deleted my Open Sans font, which is a shame :/. But at least the formatting works now, so thanks for the investigation.

Comment: So, do I have to edit the style whenever I visit a StackOverflow page?

Comment: @einpoklum No, that is what Stack Exchange should do. If you want to fix it `pacman -R ttf-open-sans`. Or your equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

### Firefox override CSS workaround

I found a way to override the CSS in Firefox thanks to [a post on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/318912/how-to-override-the-css-of-a-site-in-firefox-with-usercontent-css). I copied & updated the instructions to be current (as of FF version 56.x), I tested this to work on Windows 10 but probably would work fine on any OS.

1. Open Firefox and press <kbd>Alt</kbd> to show the top menu, then click on `Help` → `Troubleshooting Information`
2. Click the "Open Folder" button beside the `Profile Folder` entry
3. Create a folder named `chrome` in the directory that opens. Make sure "chrome" is all lower case.
4. In the `chrome` folder create a CSS file with [the name `userContent.css`](http://kb.mozillazine.org/UserContent.css)
5. Copy the following code to  `userContent.css`, replacing "example.com" with the website you want to modify and your own custom CSS, save the file, and restart Firefox: (may be a good idea to clear cache too)

```
@-moz-document domain(codereview.stackexchange.com) {
    body {
        font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif !important;
    }
}

@-moz-document domain(codereview.meta.stackexchange.com) {
    body {
        font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif !important;
    }
}
```

What this does is override the CSS rule that tells Firefox to use "Open Sans" font as 1st priority. Note that it didn't work without the `!important` flag so that needs to be there.